# IBM Watson speech to text results are only lowercase?

Tags: java, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

it looks like the speech to text transcription result is completely in lower case only ?
is there an option to enable case sensitive output ?
I'm using the java api.

best regards,
david c.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, it appears the transcription are generally case-insensitive, although proper nouns are supported in certain scenarios.

> For most languages, the service does not use capitalization in response transcripts. If capitalization is important for your application, you must capitalize the first word of each sentence and any other terms for which capitalization is appropriate.
> For US English only, the service does capitalize many proper nouns.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-basic-response#response-capitalization

I added my own custom function to capitalise the start of each new final transcription result (i.e. sentence).